# Generate a summary table with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, function

I'm currently trying to develop a spreadsheet that helps me write down malfunctioned convectors/windows inside my building (im working in the facility-management-business). Because each Floor has nearly 140 Windows and 80 convectors and we dont have a standardised way of writing down the problems/defects i wanna create a excel-sheet in Excel 2016.

Now because i have a touchscreen-laptop i wanna do me a favor and just press on the different cells in each category if there is a problem (A = broken motor, B = leakage in the pipe-system, ect.) and change its color.

If there is no problem, the Index-Color is green, if there is a problem, its red (darkred).

Now, i have the following VBA-script running, which adds a Cells-Value of 1 to each Cell and via Data-format ";;;" i hide it from being visible + switch the colors:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
Cancel = True
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D13:O148")) Is Nothing Then
Select Case Target.Interior.ColorIndex
Case xlNone, 4: Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 53
         Target.Cells.Value = 1
    Case Else: Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 53
        Target.Cells.Value = 1
End Select
End If
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeRightClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D13:O148")) Is Nothing Then
        Cancel = True
        Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 43
        Target.Cells.ClearContents
    End If
End Sub
```

(I used internet-ressources from stackoverflow and modified it, so if someone sees his script and feels offended, sorry for that).

If i press on one Cell, i can mark it as a defect (red), give it the cells.value of 1 and sum it up in the top. If i right-click on a cell i can clear it.

Now, the Problem is the following:

[image: Preview]

because each window/convector has its own specific number (31-floors in total. btw) we have to write each window/convector together for our office so our subcontractors can see which convector/window has a problem and from the labels that each possesses he knows where to work and what the problem is that was diagnosed.

So, to make it short: if i click on a cell, change its Color and add its value i wanna get the Window/Convector-Number and write it, as you can see in the picture, into the cell next to A (B4). i wanna do the same for each Error-letter in the table. Here a small example what i mean:

**-Lets say convector nr. 8 has a broken motor (A) and its pipe is leaking (B).**

**-I press on cell A and B in the table-row for windownr. 8 and mark it as red (+ it gets the hidden value 1)**

**-Summary for A and B goes up by 1 each**

**-It adds the windownumber "8" to the A- and B-Cell on the top**

**-If more convectors on that floor has this problem, it will add them after each other (if 7 is defect too, it will look like this: |   A    |        7,8         |**

This way, we can:

**-Summarize the costs and notify the customer the price for everything (each problem has fixed cost)**

**-Our Subcontractors can work independently with my co-workers without me going with them (we put labels on each convector this year)**

**-Faster and easier maintenance + lookup later in the year if problems arise**

**-Our office can finally shut the ... *hust* be quiet about it.**

So if anyone had this kind of problem and has a good idea of how i can write it down in VBA without having to manually add them to the list i would appreciate it very much.

Comment: I strongly advise against that approach. Colour is not data. What aspect of the code you need do you have difficulty with? What have you tried? What is not working? Do you get errors?

Comment: And you may want to come up with a better title. The tags already identify Excel as the application. The fact that you're asking here shows that you have a problem. So you don't need that in the title. Your question is about code to generate a summary from a table of data. That should be the title.

Comment: Sorry for posting a Question as an Answer, anyway i completly remodelled the whole Excel-Sheet and changed the code accordingly, now it works. I dont know what happened exactly but it works. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you don't use VBA to color the cells, but conditional formatting. That will be a lot easier. Use your code to enter a number into the cell you touch, or remove it. Then use worksheet formulas to calculate the totals and use conditional formatting for the fill colours. That way you don't change the colors with VBA at all.

With each cell change, you want to update the table at the top to show a comma separated list of row numbers that are marked with that category letter. You can do that by using a change event that monitors only the data entry cells and then loops through all rows of data, column by column. If the current cell has the value 1, then append the row 's floor number to the summary table at the top.

Your layout for the summary table is different from the data entry layout, so there will need to be some extra code to identify which cell to write the result to.

Here is a similar layout that I used in my code.

[image]

This worksheet change event re-calculates the values in the summary table whenever a value in the input table has been changed. You need to adjust this code to reflect your worksheet target rows and columns, but the comments should help you figure that out.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B7:G12")) Is Nothing Then
    mytargetrow = 1
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Range("B1:B3").ClearContents
    Range("D1:D3").ClearContents
    For i = 1 To 6 ' this is for six columns of data
        For j = 1 To 6 ' this is for six rows of data
            myrow = j + 6 ' adjust to the number of rows above the first row of data
            mycolumn = i + 1 ' adjust to the number of columns to the left of the A data column
            If Cells(myrow, mycolumn) = 1 Then
                ' find the target cell
                ' the arrangement of the summary table is different
                ' and the summary table is in several columns
                If i <= 3 Then
                    mytargetcolumn = 2
                Else
                    mytargetcolumn = 4
                End If
                If mytargetrow = 4 Then mytargetrow = 1 ' start in row 1 for the second column of the summary table
                If Len(Cells(mytargetrow, mytargetcolumn)) > 0 Then ' if the cell already has a value
                ' write the floor number from column A in the current row.
                    Cells(mytargetrow, mytargetcolumn) = Cells(mytargetrow, mytargetcolumn) & ", " & Cells(myrow, 1)
                Else
                     Cells(mytargetrow, mytargetcolumn) = Cells(myrow, 1)
                End If
            End If
        Next j
        mytargetrow = mytargetrow + 1
    Next i
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: If that resolved your issue, please mark the answer as described in the [tour]. If it didn't, please leave a comment, so I can follow up.

Comment: Thanks, now it works. But just a short question: what exactly makes VBA-scripted coloring bad? i mean i somehow see why if there are easier methods, just wanted to ask. Anyway, thanks for the Answer and have a nice evening.

Comment: if you use VBA to colour a cell because you just entered a 1 into it, you're basically re-creating the wheel. Excel already has that functionality built-in with conditional formatting, so you just need to configure it. That way you don't need to write any code to do what Excel already does more efficiently out of the box.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that, appreciated the comment. Thank you.